# print ajax response with php

Tags: php, ajax

I cannot get the alert to work after sending the data in ajax? Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My form:

```
  <body>

<form action="" id="form1" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="Submit">
</form>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
    // AJAX SEND POST DATA
    $('form').on('submit', function() {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'submit2.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(self).serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert("blabla");                    
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my submit2.php file.

```
<?php echo "bla"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your HTML or JQuery code. The problem is with submit2.php file. Your AJAX function is looking for a JSON response. Return a JSON response from submit2.php

**submit2.php**

```
echo json_encode(array("message"=>"Here is the message"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work still, not sure what's happening.

Comment: Is your submit2.php file in the same directory? If not adjust the path. If you have chrome check the console and network tab. If you are trying to print the data received then make a little change in JQuery. `success: function(data){if(data.message != undefined){console.log(message);}}, error: function(data){console.log(data);}` If still you are having problem, let me know with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" id="form1" method="post">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $("#form1").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'submit2.php',
        // dataType: 'json', unless you're expecting json object as server response, remove this
        data: $(self).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);                    
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

**submit2.php**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])){
        echo $_POST['firstname'] . " " . $_POST['lastname'];
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can't get the alert window to appear using, your code. Not sure why

Comment: Sidenote: Always debug your code using [firebug addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/).

Comment: Thanks, so I commented out the dataType: json and the alert started working